# Flutter - How to change google maps API key dynamically in AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Instead of hard coding api keys in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and `ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m` how to change the key dynamically anytime from backend ?

Comment: Did you get the answer? if so, can you share with us how you solved this demand? Tks

Comment: Here is a resource for you
https://mobikul.com/flutteradd-google-maps-api-key-dynamically/